# I'm wondering why my handler function is running all its functions at the same time and not waiting for one another?

Tags: c#

I'm wondering why my handler function is running all its functions at the same time and not waiting for one another?

Could someone tell me why my handler execute both func1 and func2 executes at the same time?

My method1 and method2 works perfectly and they execute while waiting for the previous to complete. But when it execute handler.

But func1 and func2 is running at async at the same time. How can I fix this?

```
public void Run()
{
       lock (_theLock)
       {
             Task.Run(async () => {
                   await method1();
                   await method2();
                   await handler();
             });
       }
}
```

Handler method which calls on func1 or 2:

```
private async Task handler() {
       await _timer.func1();
       await _timer.func2(); }
```

_timer class:

```
   public class _timer

    public async void  func1()
    {
        lock (lock)
        {
            test1();          
        }
    }

    public async void func2()
    {
        lock (lock)
        {
            test2();
        }
    }

    public async Task test1()
    {
        await method1(); // the same method as in  the run method
    }

    public async Task test2()
    {
        await method2(); // the same method as in  the run method
    }

    public async Task method1()
    {
         var test1 = await GetDataFromSource1();
         await  doStuff(test1);
     }

   public async Task func2()
   {
        await method2(); // the same method as in  the run method
   }

   public async Task method2()
   {
         var test2 = await GetDataFromSource2();
         await  doStuff(test2);
   }

 public async Task<List<items>> GetDataFromSource1() {

 // retrieves data from database SQL

}

 public async Task<List<items>> GetDataFromSource2() {

 // retrieves data from database SQL    
}

 public async Task doStuff(List<string> items) {

 // does stuff with the data

}
```

Answer (score 5):

problem 1: `async void` - the caller has no way of knowing when it completes; use `async Task` or `async ValueTask` instead; you should *almost never* use `async void`.

problem 2: you didn't `await` when calling `test1` or `test2`, so... nothing was *awaited*

problem 3: you can't use `lock` with `await` - you'll need to use a different locking primitive, perhaps `SemaphoreSlim(1,1)` (which works like a mutex)

obersvation: none of this code is *actually* truly asynchronous

Comment: @FredrikLinger fair enough - that addresses the "observation" - the rest still stands, though

Comment: By observing the current code, does it makes any sense for me to use locks?

The test1 updates the cache data every 24 hours and the func2  uses the updated cache data to do stuff.

Comment: @FredrikLinger I can't tell you whether you need some kind of synchronization - that's up to your code and scenario; however, I *can* tell you that you can't use `lock` in this case - hence why I mentioned SemaphoreSlim

Comment: Can you see the curlplit why my handler execute both functions at the same time?

Comment: @FredrikLinger yes, that is problems 1 and 2 in the answer I already posted; I mentioned them *because* they are the problems

Answer (score 1):

First thing first, you should avoid async void. 
Always use Task as return type for async methods.

Please [refer this blog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) for more details on async programming.

The other thing is await operation does not mean that the execution flow would wait until the execution of that method is complete.

It means that it will give call to method and try executing further statements.

But it will not leave the current method until all the await operations are completed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: What do you suggest I should do to make my code correct? Maybe this would give me a better understanding.

Comment: you will have to use Task as return type for func1 and func2.  Then you will have to remove lock statements from func1 and func2.

Comment: Do I actually have to return something? Because I'm setting the data returned in the cache in DoStuff method2? Can I do a return Task or something?

Comment: If return type is Task that means your async method is not returning anything.  If you want to return, let's say int, then the return type should be Task<int>.  Hope this helps.

Comment: but all the methods isn't really returning anything, since what it only does it is that it only say to method 2 to do this and that's it

Comment: Then use return type Task.  You dont need to return anything in that case.

Comment: return type task like just specify public async Task? :)